# How to make a dedicated server work on a remote server without a GPU?

Tags: steam, civilization-5

The dedicated server which is bundled in the Civ5 SDK doesn't work, how do I make it work?

There are so many thing wrong with it, it's a real adventure. If you run the SDK and select DEDICATED SERVER, many people get no response as it silently fails. If you find the server executable and run it, it has various DLL fails. There is a "fix" out there to copy the server .exe file to the game folder, which gets the server interface working but can't connect.

There is also a rumor going around that you need a GPU to run the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your dedicated server...

- Install Steam
- from within Steam install Civ5 and any DLC you might want
- run Civ5 from Steam, this will install a bunch of prerequisites, close the game
- from within Steam install Civ5 SDK
- run the SDK from Steam, this will install a bunch of prerequisite, close the SDK dialog that opens (it won't help you).
- find the steam content install location (typically `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common`)
- copy the content (everything!) of `.\Sid Meier's Civilization V` in to `.\Sid Meier's Civilization V SDK\Dedicated Server`
- now from within`.\Sid Meier's Civilization V SDK\Dedicated Server` run `CivilizationV_Server` (if you run it from the actual Civ5 folder it will run but won't connect!)
- Set up your game however you like, then click `Host Game`
- Windows defender firewall will probably pop up asking for permission; say yes.

Done :)

A few other things though. Firstly you'll need to open or forward a whole bunch of ports, either in your cloud set up or on your router, see below. Secondly you might need to launch CIV from within Steam and set the Options>Multiplayer>SMTP settings if you want notifications (but exit once you have set them). Thirdly, once you have the Civ5 server running I think you can exit Steam on the dedicated box. Fourthly, you do not need a GPU to run the dedicated server.

> TCP: 1745,1795,3074,27015-27030,27036-27037
>
> UDP: 1745,1795,3064,3074,4380,27000-27031,27036

If it's a private game you'll need to connect from you local gaming machine via IP.

Any questions or problems I'll try to help, but please make sure you are doing it exactly like this before you ask ;)